# Hiding class methods by using .call/.apply

Tags: javascript, private-members

Can someone explain what this excerpt from [Single Page Apps in Depth](http://singlepageappbook.com/maintainability1.html) means?

> A common pattern for classes (e.g. objects instantiated from a
>   prototype) is to simply mark class methods as private by starting them
>   with a underscore. *You can properly hide class methods by using
>   .call/.apply to set "this"*, but I won't show it here; it's a minor
>   detail.

I think it suggests there is a way to actually make 'private' JavaScript methods actually inaccessible instead of the convention of just marking them with an underscore, but I can't imagine what an implementation would look like, nor how it would be used.

Comment: +1 for the link to Single Page Apps ebook! thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var Treasure = function(){  
  function locate(){
    return this.x * this.y + 31337;
  }

  function Treasure(x, y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  Treasure.prototype.find = function find(){
    return locate.call(this);
  };

  return Treasure;
}();
```

`locate` is a shared private function for the constructor and prototype methods. Using `call` it can act like a method and utilize `this`.

A more complete implementation of this concept is that of interface objects and implementation objects. Instead of having a few random functions-as-methods (similar to locate above) you actually create a whole class that is private. Every external creation of the interface results in two objects crated: the public shell interface and the private implementation object. This allows you to expose an interface that provides a different, perhaps easier to use, API publicly. Or can allow you to reuse single private implementation objects for entire groups of interface objects.

This is actually how the DOM is specified to work (usually not implemented in js though). The interface objects (element and node objects for example) are specifically required to wrap the underlying implementation that actually does the word. The exposed objects are little more than shells that forward property access and method invocation.

Dom.js is a full blown DOM implementation made in js. An interesting technique I got acquainted with while working in it was completely automated generation of public interfaces. This is the purpose of IDL: the public API is literally generated automatically, leaving only the private implementation to actually be created. What this really means its possible to create things like this without consulting a human: https://github.com/Benvie/svgstuff/blob/master/lib/defs.js

Answer (score 1):

You can see the two types of variables in this example.  You will note that the first one is private, the second is accessible publicly:

```
function x() {
    var _var1 = "hello";
    this.var2 = "world";
    x.prototype.innerTest = function() {
        console.log("inner var1: " + _var1);
        console.log("inner var2: " + this.var2);
    }
}

var y = new x;
console.log("var1: " + y._var1);
console.log("var2: " + y.var2);

// var1: undefined
// var2: world
```

Running the inner test shows that *var1* can be accessed from within the class:

```
y.innerTest();
// var1: hello
// var2: world
```